# Finding distance from point to line determined by vector

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, vectors

We are given a point, b. 
We are given a vector, v, which determines a line. 
We are given a point c such that there exists a line through c which has the same direction as the line determined by v. (Obviously we also know a vector, c, given this point).

How can we find the distance from the point b to the line determined by c?

I know that we have to find a projection and use that to find the orthogonal line from b to the line determined by c. However, I have no idea how to find the line determined by the point c and the direction of the vector v.

If the line determined by the vector v, and the new line through c, have the same direction, then they are parallel. However, I'm not sure how to calculate what this line actually is.

EDIT: Here's an example:

```
b = point (1, 2, 2, 4)
v = vector (1, 7, 7, 1)
c = point (4, 1, 2, 2)
```

I'm confident that I can work this out on my own, once I can figure out how to determine the line through c with direction given by the vector v.

Comment: I think the best is to provide with an example. We can help you to wokr it out and then you may generalize it...

Comment: I've edited in an example to illustrate.

Comment: @CCSab the *derivative* (Which is by the way very easy to calculate), is the calculus way of saying what you chose to be correct. That's where the Mathematics is in this case. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the line is given by $$ l(t) = c + tv $$ the vector from the Point c on the line to b (not on the line) is $$(b-c) $$ now you can compute the projection of this vector onto the line by
$$proj(b-c) = \frac{ (b-c) \cdot v }{ ||v||^2 }v$$ Now you can compute the rejection, the vector from the projection to b by $$ rej = (b-c) - proj(b-c) $$ it's norm is the distance you are looking for $$ dist = || rej || $$

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by why the line is given by that equation. Can you explain why that is? Am I mistaken that the line and the original vector, v, are parallel?

Comment: @CCSab This is the parametric equation of a line threw a point c parallel to a vector v. From a given origin you can "go along" a vector representing the point c and then, doing the head-to-tails method of visualising vector addition, you can "go along" v. As t, a scalar, varies you can visit all points on the line.

Comment: @CCSab Have you worked out my approach? It isn't difficult anymore I think...

Comment: @imranfat Yes! I've worked the problems in both ways and it works. Looking at it from different perspectives really helps clarify what is going on geometrically

Comment: Does this also come in simple? like the problem?

Comment: Is the rejection then just the perpendicular component?

Comment: Ah, I just found my own answer, it looks like that's exactly what it is. Searching was very frustrating because of all the articles on projection/rejection/reflection in the context of therapy.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Maybe you want to find stationary points of $f(t)=| c+tv-b|^2$, $t$ a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try. You can set up a plane with vector $v$ as its normal, plane passing though point $b$. It would look like $x+7y+7z+w=33$ 
Now you can set up a 4dim line with $v$ as its directional vector and passing through point $c$, so that could look like $<4,1,2,2> + k<1,7,7,1>$ so that gives $x=4+k, y=1+7k, z=2+7k, w=2+k$ Substitute this in your plane equation and find the value of $k$. That gives you the point of intersection of the line with the plane. Calculate the distance between $b$ and the point of intersection with the distance formula.